# Mysql subquery with joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table 'service' which contains details about serviced vehicles. It has an id and Vehicle_registrationNumber which is a foreign key. Whenever vehicle is serviced, a new record is made. So, for example if I make a service for car with registration ABCD, it will create new row, and I will set car_reg, date and car's mileage in the service table (id is set to autoincreament) (e.g 12 | 20/01/2012 | ABCD | 1452, another service for the same car will create row 15 | 26/01/2012 | ABCD | 4782).

Now I want to check if the car needs a service (the last service was either 6 or more months ago, or the current mileage of the car is more than 1000 miles since last service), to do that I need to know the date of last service and the mileage of the car at the last service. So I want to create a subquery, that will return one row for each car, and the row that I'm interested in is the newest one (either with the greatest id or latest endDate). I also need to join it with other tables because I need this for my view (I use CodeIgniter but don't know if it's possible to write subqueries using CI's ActiveRecord class)

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT *
FROM (`service`)
JOIN `vehicle` ON `service`.`Vehicle_registrationNumber` = `vehicle`.`registrationNumber`
JOIN `branch_has_vehicle` ON `branch_has_vehicle`.`Vehicle_registrationNumber` = `vehicle`.`registrationNumber`
JOIN `branch` ON `branch`.`branchId` = `branch_has_vehicle`.`Branch_branchId`
GROUP BY `service`.`Vehicle_registrationNumber` )
AS temp


WHERE `vehicle`.`available` != 'false'
AND `service`.`endDate` <= '2011-07-20 20:43'
OR service.serviceMileage  < vehicle.mileage - 10000
```

Comment: The statement you create would not work because a not so old service entry would be filtered out. Another hint miles should be 1000 or 10000 .. differs in text and sql-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `service`.`Vehicle_registrationNumber`, Max(`service`.`endDate`) as lastService,
   MAX(service.serviceMileage) as lastServiceMileage, vehicle.*
FROM `service`
INNER JOIN `vehicle` 
  ON `service`.`Vehicle_registrationNumber` = `vehicle`.`registrationNumber`
INNER JOIN `branch_has_vehicle` 
  ON `branch_has_vehicle`.`Vehicle_registrationNumber` = `vehicle`.`registrationNumber`
INNER JOIN `branch` 
  ON `branch`.`branchId` = `branch_has_vehicle`.`Branch_branchId`
WHERE vehicle.available != 'false'
GROUP BY `service`.`Vehicle_registrationNumber` 
HAVING lastService<=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 6 MONTH) 
   OR lastServiceMileage < vehicle.mileage - 10000
```

;

I hope I have no typo in it ..

Comment: Great, this works as expected and it's much simpler and clearer than my approach with subquires. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

If instead of using * in the subquery you specify the fields you need (which is always good practice anyway), most databases have a MAX() function that returns the maximum value within the group. 
Actually, you don't even need the subquery. You can do the joins and use the MAX in the SELECT statement. Then you can do something like

```
SELECT ...., MAX('service'.'end_date') AS LAST_SERVICE
...
GROUP BY 'service'.'Vehicle_registrationNumber'
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: You're right, I didn't quite remember how MAX() works, I thought it would only return one record per statement and I didn't think about using it together with GROUP BY. Thanks very much for your help!